# Updating objects in RoR with API call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

I am trying to configure my ruby on rails application in such a manner that I can update values with http Patch calls from for example a Angular app. Currently I have the following method of which I expect it to work:

**users_controller.rb**

```
  def safe_params
    params.require(:id).permit(:email)
  end

  def update
    user = User.find(params[:id])
    user.update_attributes(safe_params)
    render nothing: true, status: 204
  end
```

However, I get the following error when I pass some simple JSON:

> undefined method `permit' for "500":String

Passed JSON:

```
{"email":"newadres@live.com", "id":500}
```

Do you guys know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `require` is used to fetch a nested structure, raising an error if it is missing. It doesn't make much sense in this case.

Comment: Are you running the latest Rails version? That does seem to be [by the book](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you are misunderstanding the purpose of [`require`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require) and [`permit`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit).

`require` is generally used in combination with a `Hash` and a form, to make sure the controller receives an Hash that exists and contains some expected attributes. Note that `require` will either raise, or extract the value associated with the required key, and return that value.

`permit` works as a filter, it explicitly allows only certain fields. The returned value is the original params Hash, whitelisted.

In your case, `require` does not make any sense at all, unless you pass a nested JSON like this one

```
{"user": {"email":"newadres@live.com", "id":500}}
```

but even in that case, it would be

```
params.require(:user).permit(:email)
```

In your current scenario, the correct code is

```
params.permit(:email)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change the order between require and permit, like that

```
params.permit(:email).require(:id)
```

because permit returns the entire hash, while require returns the specific parameter

Reference [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-require)

**UPDATE**

However, as others pointed out, you shouldn't use *require* with a single attribute, as it is most commonly used for hashes instead

Comment: Although this doesn't raise an error, it's not what the OP expects. `require(:id)` merely returns the `id` parameter, i.e. `"500"`

Comment: It's interesting that the definition of `require` contradicts the example given at the top of that page.

Comment: This is the way ActionController:Parameters behaves, I think it allows to have all checks in a single line

Comment: @EmilianoDellaCasa well, the OP wants to pass the result to `update_attributes` and `update_attributes("500")` doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @tadman indeed, the description is misleading. `require` doesn't mark anything.

Comment: @Stefan ok now I got what you mean, I will update my answer to avoid misunderstandings

Comment: The chaining order of require followed by permit is correct. The problem is with the param sent to require. It needs to be a hash of with the keys that could be filtered on in permit.

Answer (score 0):

One way to fix this, keeping with the spirit of the Rails docs:

```
def safe_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email)
end
```

And update the json:

```
{"user": {"email":"newadres@live.com"}, "id": 500}
```